# Can not use jsonpath expression in Postman

Tags: api, testing, postman, expression, jsonpath

I have Json like this, and i tried to print a value i wanted by using JSonpath expression, detail is i wanted to print first_name of user has id = 10

```
{
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 6,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Michael",
            "last_name": "Lawson",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Lindsay",
            "last_name": "Ferguson",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Tobias",
            "last_name": "Funke",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Byron",
            "last_name": "Fields",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "George",
            "last_name": "Edwards",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Rachel",
            "last_name": "Howell",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
        "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
    }
}
```

I wrote a simple script in tests in postman to do that

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
let x = jsonData.data[?(@.id==8)].first_name)
console.log(x)
```

But the response in tests is

```
There was an error in evaluating the test script:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

[the result as like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKZe5.png)

Comment: JSONpath isn't part of Postman so you wouldn't be able to use it in the sandbox environment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find()` to find the object match your condition.

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
let x = jsonData.data.find(item => item.id === 8).first_name;
console.log(x);
//Lindsay
```